# Image Analytics using Sequence File

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Before directly jumping onto the question, I want to tell something about Sequence Files in Hadoop
**SequenceFile** is a flat file consisting of binary key/value pairs (although you can always use Text data type for the key). In fact, internally Hadoop uses SequenceFile to store the temporary outputs of maps.

The other objective of using SequenceFile is to 'pack' many small files into a single large SequenceFile for the MapReduce computation since the design of Hadoop prefers large files (Let us assume that Hadoop default block size for data is 64MB).

That was not precise but a brief description about the sequence files in hadoop.
Now,
Let us look into an example.

Let us assume we have lots of small images and we need to remove the redundant image to save space in the secondary storage. For this we cannot go searhing for similar filenames of every image files and segregate them out manually. First of all that is painful and secondly it will take a lot of time. So whose gonna do that for us? 
Mapreduce!!
What we can do is we can just calculate the **MD5/SHA1/SHA-256** of the image files and put them as keys and emit them out from the mapper so that we get the output as a list of pictures which aren't redundant. Let us look at the codes for the same !!
**BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFileMapper: *Connverts the binary input to Hadoop Sequence input***

```
package com.sqence;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger;


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile {

    //Log4JLogger logger = new Log4JLogger().getLogger();

    public static class BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFileMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, BytesWritable> {

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //logger.info("map method called..");

            String uri = value.toString();
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
            FSDataInputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
                java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 1024];

                while( in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) >= 0 ) {
                    bout.write(buffer);
                }
                context.write(value, new BytesWritable(bout.toByteArray()));
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeStream(in);
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
//      if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
//          System.err.println("Usage: BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile <in Path for url file> <out pat for sequence file>");
//          System.exit(2);
//      }


        Job job =Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFile.class);
        job.setMapperClass(BinaryFilesToHadoopSequenceFileMapper.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
        Path p= new Path(args[1]);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,p);
        p.getFileSystem(conf).delete(p, true);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }


}
```

After we convert the Binary Files to Hadoop Sequence Files, we will use mapreduce to search for the duplicate images
**ImageDuplicateMapper**, Here the MD5 hash of the image files are emitted from the mapper as keys and the URI to the image files are generated as values

```
package com.sqence;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public  class ImageDuplicatesMapper extends Mapper<Text, BytesWritable, Text, Text>{
public void map(Text key, BytesWritable value, Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {

    //get the md5 for this specific file

     String md5Str;
     try {
         md5Str = calculateMd5(value.getBytes());
          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              context.setStatus("Internal error - can't find the algorithm for calculating the md5");
                                return;
                        }
                        Text md5Text = new Text(md5Str);
                        //put the file in the map where the md5 is the key, so duplicates will
                        // be grouped together for the reduce function
                context.write(md5Text, key);
                }
//md5 calculator
                static String calculateMd5(byte[] imageData) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

                        //get the md5 for this specific data

                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

                md.update(imageData);

                byte[] hash = md.digest();



                // Below code of converting Byte Array to hex

                String hexString = new String();

                for (int i=0; i < hash.length; i++) {

                        hexString += Integer.toString( ( hash[i] & 0xff ) + 0x100, 16).substring( 1 );

                }

                return hexString;
          }
        }
```

From the mapper phase we get the MD5 hash of the images as keys and URI to the image files as values. From where the same goes to the reduce phase. Here's the code

```
package com.sqence;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;


public class ImageDupsReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {



                public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)

                                                        throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                        //Key here is the md5 hash while the values are all the image files that

                        // are associated with it. for each md5 value we need to take only

                        // one file (the first)

                        Text imageFilePath = null;

                        for (Text filePath : values) {

                                imageFilePath = filePath;

                                break;//only the first one

                        }

                        // In the result file the key will be again the image file path.

                        context.write(imageFilePath, key);

                }

        }
```

And last but not the least, The `**ImageDriver**` class

```
package com.sqence;


import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;

//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.NLineInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;





public class ImageDriver extends Configured implements Tool
{

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
          //getting configuration object and setting job name
          Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      Job job = new Job(conf, "Word Count hadoop-0.20");

      //setting the class names
      job.setJarByClass(ImageDriver.class);
      job.setMapperClass(ImageDuplicatesMapper.class);
      job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
      //job.setCombinerClass(WordCountReducer.class);
      job.setReducerClass(ImageDupsReducer.class);


      //setting the output data type classes
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
      Path p= new Path(args[1]);
      //to accept the hdfs input and outpur dir at run time
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, p);
        p.getFileSystem(conf).delete(p, true);
      return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ImageDriver(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
    }
```

Hope, you are still there with me. I have just learned the Sequence File Format and coded the problem statement as a matter of practice.The program works as expected and gives the accurate output. 

Let's come to my question. Now I am pretty clear that I can save space by filtering out redundant images from the secondary storage device. I want to ask anyone who is reading the question
**FIRST QUESTION :Can  I do the same work to filter out redundant videos too? If yes then should I need to upload all thee video files to the HDFS?**
**SECOND QUESTION: In image filtering, I need to calculate the hash of the image** (which will be input in a Binary Stream)**. Meanwhile Video files, say movies, are very large files and I believe calculating hash of those files is sure to give a severe performance hit. Is there any other way I can filter out redundant videos from a secondary storage device through less costly approach?** Atleast other than calculating hash.

Thank you for going through the question? Please pardon me if way of asking the question seems incorrect to you.
Thankyou in advance for the help. :)